# ${file%/*} replaces spaces with underscores

Tags: bash, filenames, spaces, dirname

converting mp3 to ogg-files is dine by a simple script.

But: When i construct the new pathname and filename
with

```
    # set the 'file' variable first
    file="$1"
    # get extension; everything after last '.'
    ext=${file##*.} 
    mp32ogg --verbose --delete --quality=0 --rename="${file%/*}/`basename "$file" .${file##*.}`"  "$1"|| exit 1
```

the file-/pathnames that have spaces will be created with underscores.

And i see no reason... all help is welcome!

Appelgebak

Answer (score 0):

By default, `mp32ogg` automatically replaces spaces (and lots of other non-alphabetic characters) with underscores in the output filename.  To suppress this behavior, pass in the (undocumented) `--no-replace` flag.

Comment: Hm. 
Using 
mp32ogg --verbose --delete --no_replace --quality=0 --rename="${file%/*}/`basename "$file" .${file##*.}`"  "$1"|| exit 1

leads to:
`mp32ogg v0.11-gentoo-r2
(c) 2000-2002 Nathan Walp
Released without warranty under the terms of the Artistic License

Unknown option: no_replace
`

Comment: @user605447: obviously its `--no-replace` , not `--no_replace`. Maybe Adam Rosenfield forgot to set the `--no-replace` option on the post ;-)